# Dateformat change in Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, momentjs, date-format

I am using moment.js to format date

```
orderStartDate = start.format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM:ss');
orderEndDate = end.format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM:ss');

$('#dateStart').val(orderStartDate);
$('#dateEnd').val(orderEndDate);

<input type="datetime-local" class="hide" name="dateStart" id="dateStart" value="@ViewBag.DateStart" />
<input type="datetime-local" class="hide" name="dateEnd" id="dateEnd" value="@ViewBag.DateEnd" />
```

In my local this shows for example a correct format: `4/27/2020 12:00:00 AM` but when I published it in the server it changed to this format: `27/04/2020 12:00:00 AM` and this result to null when calling to controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? dateStart = null, DateTime? dateEnd = null)
```

How can I retain same format to my local to `mm/dd/yyy` or `4/27/2020 12:00:00 AM` ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably send the date to the server in ISO8601 format.

Comment: [DateTime has no format.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/) The display format is only for the string representation of the datetime values - which is governed by the culture info. You shouldn't rely on the default culture info of the server, but either use an explicit format when displaying the datetime values or manually setting the culture.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest with custom date format, you can change parameter as

```
public ActionResult Index(string dateStart = "", string dateEnd = "")
```

and use `Date.TryParseExact` inside action method to your date format.

Answer (score 0):

Because browser is sending some format and server is using another format.

Also there can be diffenrece between 
Moment UI visible format and Browser sent data format.
What is browser sending has to be in same format as server is expecting.

On the client side in razor do export

```
orderStartDate = start.format('@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern');
```

This could be usefull as hint.

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-EN");
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM:ss";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```